# Why do CentOS MySQL repostitories have different configurations for different chipsets?

Tags: mysql, centos

I installed two new CentOS 6.4 installations; one on an i686 VPS and the other on a physical x86_64 desktop, installed MySQL 5.1.69 on both using `yum install mysql-server` using CentOS's repository, and made no other changes.  `SHOW VARIABLES;` are identical on both except for the following.  Why are they different?  Does one have "better" values than another?  If so, why is one better than the other.

```
+---------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
|                           |         i386          |         x86_64          |
+---------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
| max_binlog_cache_size     | 4294963200            | 18446744073709500000    |
| max_seeks_for_key         | 4294967295            | 18446744073709500000    |
| max_write_lock_count      | 4294967295            | 18446744073709500000    |
| myisam_max_sort_file_size | 2146435072            | 9223372036853720000     |
| myisam_mmap_size          | 4294967295            | 18446744073709500000    |
| plugin_dir                | /usr/lib/mysql/plugin | /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin |
+---------------------------+-----------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Once I saw Michael's and Nathan's answer, it was obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit. Those values are unsigned INTs, which is limited to the values you see above (4,294,967,295 for 32bit, 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 for 64bit). The sort_file_size appears to be half the maximum possible values.

Answer (score 2):

One architecture is 32-bit and the other is 64-bit. Those values correspond more or less exactly to the maximum unsigned and signed 32-bit and 64-bit vaules.